# How to install a shared library in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, libraries, chkrootkit

As part of my research work I have to study a rootkit. So I downloaded [ncom](http://packetstormsecurity.org/files/99782/Ncom-Libcall-Hijacking-Rootkit.html) rootkit and tried installing. It didn't have any installation files.

Comment: Did it create a **.so** file ?

Comment: It comes with a .so file libncom.so

Comment: The details of the lib is: **ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), stripped**

Answer (score 2):

First, how do you know it's not installed?  That sounds frivolous, but it *is* a root kit, and it's job is to hide installed things.  Believing that you have a rootkit installed on a system makes everything that system tells you suspect.

This page: http://www.aggro.it/files/papers/ncom.html hints a bit about how it's installed.  Looks like you might be able to use the shared-object file on individual executables by exporting LD_PRELOAD set to the ncom .so file name.

It also looks like the file /etc/ld.so.preload might be a way to get it dynmically linked in every executable.

Comment: That link says to run cat `/etc/ld.so.preload` to find if its there. But when I run, its not there in my system. `ld.so.preload` - What is the importance of that?